# Do Menger sponge fractals appear in "The Lego Movie"

Tags: lego, the-lego-movie, lego-cinematic-universe

I saw this picture of a [Menger sponge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge):

[image: View through the centre of an M4 model Menger sponge]

It looks like several of the scenes (memory, I don't have photos) from *The Lego Movie* either in Vitruvius room or in the connections between the worlds.

Here is one clip from one video that shows a little of the "between worlds":

Did the creators of *The Lego Movie* include Menger sponge style fractals in their artwork?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word, no. I've been through both Lego movies (as well as the Lego Batman movies and Lego Ninjago movie in case you're mis-remembering) and there are no scenes with these particular fractals.

That being said, it might interest you to learn that [Matt Ebb](https://mattebb.cargo.site/The-Lego-Movie) of Animal Logic is a specialist in [using fractal geometry for animated set design](http://mattebb.com/blog/weblog/siggraph-2017/) and designed the "point-logic" for the tools used to render the sets into Lego, so it's likely that there *are* fractals on screen in the film, albeit used in a less overt fashion, to make repeating objects like clouds and scenery.

[image]